# change the color of superpixels in python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to change the color of superpixels from an image in black/white and save the new white/black image.
I use slic for superpixel algorithm:

```
segments = slic(img, n_segments = 100, sigma = 5)
```

I tried to loop over each unique superpixel from segments and set the value 255 for white and 0 for black.
Also, I have an array `y` which contains values of 0 and 1. The length of this `y` array is the same as the number of unique superpixels and the new color of the superpixel is related to this array.
Here is what I've tried:

```
for i in np.unique(segments):
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
    if y[i] == 1:
        mask[segments == i] = 255
```

So, if the value at position `i` from `y` is `1` then the "i" superpixel should have the color white. Otherwise, the superpixel should be black.

The above code isn't working, I've got no errors but all values from mask are 0 and there should be also some of 255 (for white).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
vis = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
for ii in np.unique(segments):
    # construct a mask for the segment
    print("[x] inspecting segment {}, for {}".format(ii, 57))
    mask2 = np.ones(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
    if pred[ii] == 1:
        mask2[segments == ii] = 255
        vis[segments == ii] = 255
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually directly index the `y` array with your superpixels:

```py
mask = y[segments]
```

Or, if you want to make sure you get 0/255 uint8:

```py
yu8 = np.where(y == 1, 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)
mask = yu8[segments]
```

Yes, NumPy is awesome! You can read more about NumPy indexing here:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html